# Count all resulting values outside foreach loop

Tags: php

I would like to count all characters in text files in certain path, so i've wrote the following code

```
<?PHP

$files = glob('my/files/path/*.txt', GLOB_BRACE); 

foreach($files as $file) { 

$str = file_get_contents($file) or dir("can not read file");

$numCharSpace = strlen($str);

echo "Counted " .$numCharSpace. " character(s).<br>";

} 

?>
```

Let say, we have 4 files inside this path so it will print out the following

```
Counted 201 character(s).
Counted 99 character(s).
Counted 88 character(s).
Counted 112 character(s).
```

How can i get the total of all which should be `500 character(s)` so how to print out the count of all results which are inside `foreach();` loop.

Comment: `$total = 0; foreach(...) {$total += $numCharSpace;} echo $total;`

Comment: Sum up? You are just getting file sizes in bytes.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol works perfect, thanks a lot

Comment: @revo can you improve my code, i want to count characters inside text files only characters without spaces

Comment: Counting all characters except whitespaces (spaces, newlines, carriage returns, ...)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `strlen` you get the number of the bytes of the file. So, you can as well get that directly, without the need to read the file contents.

```
$numberOfChars = array_sum(
    array_map('filesize', glob('my/files/path/*.txt', GLOB_BRACE))
);
```

What this does is get the file size for each one of the files returned by `glob`, and sum them using `array_sum`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a variable to sum. Then you could use [`filesize()`](https://php.net/filesize) to get total bytes of the file instead of load it:

```
$files = glob('my/files/path/*.txt', GLOB_BRACE);
$total = 0;
foreach($files as $file) {
  $numCharSpace = filesize($file);
  $total += $numCharSpace ;
}
echo "Counted " .$total. " character(s).<br>";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?PHP

$files = glob('my/files/path/*.txt', GLOB_BRACE); 
$Total = 0;
foreach($files as $file) { 

$str = file_get_contents($file) or dir("can not read file");

$numCharSpace = strlen($str);

echo "Counted " .$numCharSpace. " character(s).<br>";
$Total += $numCharSpace;

} 
echo "Total " .$Total. " characters.<br>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code should work :

$files = glob('my/files/path/*.txt', GLOB_BRACE);

$numCharSpace = 0;

foreach($files as $file) {

$str = file_get_contents($file) or dir("can not read file");

$numCharSpace =  $numCharSpace + strlen($str);

}

echo "Counted " .$numCharSpace. " character(s).
";